# Configure NGINX / varnish to work with SignalR websockets?

Tags: iis, nginx, signalr, varnish

I am using NGINX to offload SSL and then using varnish to load balance/cache responses from IIS8.

```
i.e. ssl -> nginx -> varnish -> iis8
```

This works perfectly. SignalR using long polling works fine - all my timeouts etc are properly configured.

Now I'm trying to get SignalR and websockets to work with this config; without success. To simplify things I've tried the following two set ups:

> 1. nginx -> iis8 ([with these settings](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html))
> 2. varnish -> iis8 ([with these settings](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/websockets.html))

Neither of these work. I keep getting this error in Chrome:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://xxxxxxxx' failed: Unexpected response code: 500

and this from IIS:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Not a valid web socket request.
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.ServerRequest.AcceptWebSocketRequest(Func`2 callback)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(HostContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.CallHandler.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinCallContext.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBasehttpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object extraData)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallContextAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

It appears that something is not being correctly forwarded to IIS or IIS is being picky about something. Can anyone point me towards a working config for this set up?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm just researching how I can put varnish in front of a site using signalr

Comment: Didn't get anywhere... please comment if you do.

Comment: So I've just set this up similar, couldn't think of a solution for websockets (since I imagine varnish will just ignore that incoming connection). I went with long polling too. I just added an exclude for /signal-r to the varnish vcl config

sub vcl_recv {

        if (req.url ~ "signalr/") {
                return (pass);
        }

I also had to ensure I issued a PURGE whenever I have new data, which limits the usefulness of varnish but the data I push is also served on page load.

Note: this will only support long polling I guess

Comment: Have you seen this? https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/websockets.html .. never mind - I see you actually linked to this further up